# I have big file in which each line is in json format , I want to extract only few attributes from that lines..how can i do that.?

Tags: python, json

```
import json
f = open('/home/ashish/Desktop/Projects/TestFile1.json',"r")
d1 = []
for line in f:
    d1.append(line)
    json_dict = json.load(''.join(d1))
    print (json_dict)
    d1 = []
```

Comment: adding an example of the JSON file would greatly help us.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an iterative JSON paraser like `ijson`. This module is an iterative JSON parsers and treats JSON as a stream, rather than as a block file, see this [documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ijson/) for further details. This module will allow you to just extract the required attributes from each JSON document as you iterate through it.